# How to get mouse input from extended frame?

Tags: c++, windows, window, mouseevent, dwm

I have a window which has a extended frame. It looks like this:
[image: The window]

I've followed all steps in MSDN's guide for extended frames: [Custom Window Frame Using DWM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb688195(v=vs.85).aspx).

But the problem is: I can't capture mouse movement over the extended frame. I don't receive the `WM_MOUSEMOVE` message, and `WM_NCMOUSEMOVE` is only received on the resize area and on the top part of the extended frame, which is not what I need.

I've already tried `SetCapture` but it doesn't allows me to minimize, maximize, close, move nor resize the window, not to mention that it shows the "Working..." cursor.

**Does someone know how to solve this?**

Answer (score 0):

The problem was simpler than I thought. It was a naive response to WM_NCHITTEST: "if it's not a window border, then it's HTNOWHERE". Changing it to HTCLIENT solved my problem.

A weird thing is that **that MSDN page** tells us to use HTNOWHERE.